# Check content a url for find word

Tags: php

I want check in content a site that did there are some word in it site or no?

**Demo:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/CQh18s

I tried as:

```
    $url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/":
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $link    = array(
        "Top",
        "Questions",
        "Favorite",
        "Tags",
        "ago",
        "vote",
        "answers"
    );
    $resulet = "";
    foreach ($link as $val) {
        if (strstr($contents, $val)){
            $resulet += '1';
        }else{
            $resulet += '0';
        }
    }
    echo $resulet;
    if ($resulet != 0) {
        echo 'FALSE';
    }else{
        echo 'TRUE';
    }
```

Comment: Ok I'm not sure what you are asking, are you trying to find a word *IN* a url?

Comment: Do you have a problem with loading text from an URL -or- do you have a problem with with searching strings inside some other string?

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this it's helpful to do some initial debugging:

1. Do a `var_dump($contents);` first to ensure you're getting the searchable content you expect.
2. Do a `var_dump($resulet);` to ensure that your resulting variable is what you expect.

Without further clarification it seems you're trying to create a numeric increment variable in `$resulet` but doing it with string variables.

The cURL part of your code looks good, so I suspect that if you do this you'll receive the results you expect:

```
$resulet = 0;
foreach ($link as $val) {
  $resulet += strstr($contents, $val) ? 1 : 0;
}
var_dump($resulet);
```

If not, you may need to change your `strstr` to `stristr` to make the search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you are not letting curl to follow redirections. As @rdlowrey said is just a matter of dumping the `$contents` var to realize that the page has a new location.

To let curl follow redirections, just add these options before your `curl_exec`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```

Besides that, why using `$resulet` as a counter and not treating it as an integer?

```
$resulet = 0;
...
$resulet += 1;
```